# How to Iterate Over and Acces Parts of a Map in Groovy

Tags: groovy, dictionary, for-loop, iterator

I made a map:

```
def topTen = (1..10).collect { [:].withDefault{[]} }
for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {

topTen[i].put("null", i+1)

}
```

How can I grab the second part (Value) of an entry in this map and use in a comparison with another (Value) from another entry in another map?

Comment: As an aside, this does the same as your code with less typing ;-) `def topTen = (1..10).collect { [ 'null':it ] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to Ray's answer, if you wanted to compare the first and fourth values, you could do:

```
def (a, b) = topTen[ 0, 3 ].'null'
assert a == b
```

Which (obviously) is false, so would throw the assertion error:

```
Dec 2, 2011 9:07:22 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize
WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:
Assertion failed: 

assert a == b
       | |  |
       1 |  4
         false
```

Comment: I see, thanks.  What does the `.'null'` in `topTen[ 0, 3 ].'null'` do?  I sortof get it but I'm still not solid on this functional notation stuff, using `__.__` ...

Comment: @blaughli you've added the string 'null' as the key to your maps. So it just gets the values for this key in the first and fourth entry

Comment: Ok , think I've got it.  At least I'm GETTING it :)  Thanks as always))

Answer (score 0):

```
def topTen = (1..10).collect {
    [:].withDefault{[] } }
for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    topTen[i].put("null", i+1)
}
def other=[[null:1],[null:2]]
if(topTen[0]['null']==other[0]['null'])
    println 'equal'

if(topTen[0].get('null')==other[0]['null'])
    println 'equal'
if(topTen[0].'null'==other[0]['null'])
    println 'equal'
```

Comment: Thanks Ray!  I can certainly use this

Comment: see edits for a few other examples of syntax for getting stuff